# Retrieve values from configuration table in query where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to build a SQL Server 2012 query that retrieves values from a configuration table. The code looks like this:

```
Product
product_types product_description
001 Milk 
002 Butter
003 Oatmeal
```

Configuration_table

```
product_nr
001
003
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE product.types in (select product_nr from configuration_table)
```

Only 001 and 003 should be shown. But this query has no results. How can this be corrected?

Thanks for your response!

Comment: Data types for product.types and Configuration_table.product_nr?

Comment: hi jarlh thanks for your response. the product_types and product_nr are nvarchar data types

Comment: I'd have used integer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query seems good but still not working try to Trim column which are used in where condition

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE TRIM(product.types) in (select TRIM(product_nr) from configuration_table)
```